# How to Programatically Dial a Phone number in the Android SDK?

Tags: android, dtmf

How do you programatically do this in the Android SDK:

1. Dial a phone number
2. Bypass the keypad screen
3. Send additional DTMF after the number is dialed
4. Bypass the send DTMF tone prompt

I have managed to do 1 till 3 by dialing +555-1212w1234 but I am wondering if anyone knows how to bypass the send DTMF tone prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot inject DTMF codes into the call audio stream at this time. There are some proposals being discussed now for adding this capability to Android.

Sorry!

Comment: is it possible to open a dialer in on going call ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996411/android-how-to-open-dialer-with-phone-number-during-call

Answer (score 0):

Your #4 is not doable. The best you can do is 1 to 3. I use comma (,) for 2 second pause, and add more commas if needed.